# Which approach we can follow to build large & dynamic PDF files from HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, pdf, word-pdf

I want to create the following:-

1. We have a custom SharePoint list >> which contain items with attachments.
2. Now I want to show the items' attachments inside a PDF file with the following format (to show 2 images on each row), for example if we have 4 attachments inside a list item >> then the pdf should be as follow:-

[image]

Now I know that I can create an HTML from our Power Apps which contain the needed info + the images content >> pass it to a flow >> then using the OneDrive connector i can create a file based on the HTML >> convert the HTML to PDF. but this approach has a limitation that the converted file can be a maximum of 2 MB, while in our cases some file will exceed 10 MB.

On the other side, i can NOT benefit from the 2 word connectors:-

[image]

because in our case we can not have a predefined templates , as the number of attachment can vary from 1 attachment to up to 16 attachments..

so, can anyone advice what approach we can follow to achieve our requirements? of creating dynamic and large (greater than 2 MB) PDF which contain list item's attachments and text?

Thanks

Comment: Add gallery in your Power App app, show two image in one line then use [PDF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/how-to/pdf-function) to print gallery to PDF file. Let me know if works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP thanks for your reply, the issue with the PDF Function is that it is currently on Experimental phase.. and we are suppose to go live with the power apps on late January 2024.. so not sure if we should use this experimental feature or not? and what can be the sequences of using this experimental feature if MS chose to change it later on ?